# When python descriptor method would be called?

Tags: python, descriptor

I simulate some data using python descriptor.

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0 

    def __get__(self, instance, obj):
        print("is getting number")
        return self.number

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print("is setting number")
        self.number = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)

num = Number()
num = 2 
print(num + 7)
```

the output:

```
9
```

It seems successfully call the method `__get__` and `__set__`, but i don't know why there's no output message `is getting number` or `is setting number`.

I'm not sure whether python call the descriptor method or not.

my question is when descriptor method would be called?

I summary my origin guess:

1. get

   - When use `obj.prop` to get property and the prop is another object which is setting descriptor
   - when calculate some expression should get value such as `a + 5`. If a is have descriptor and will call `__get__`
   - If a object simulate a function will call `__get__` to get function body first, and then call `__call__` to run the function.
2. set

   - When the object appear in the left side of assignment statement such as `obj = 5`

But I must be wrong, i need someone to tell me the right concept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your descriptors are not being called, and there is no way to write a descriptor or anything else to do what you seem to want.

When you do `num = 2`, you have thrown away your `Number` object and set the variable `num` to the ordinary number 2.  When you then add 7 to it, it equals 9, because it's just a regular number.  Your `Number` class is not involved in any way.

Descriptors allow you to hook into what happens when you do `obj.foo` or `obj.foo = blah`.  In these cases it is `foo` that is the descriptor, not `obj`, and the descriptor only works when it is an attribute.  There is no way to change what happens when you do `obj = blah`, where `obj` is a bare name (i.e., no dots or `[]`).  In relation to your guess:

1. get

   - When use obj.prop to get property and the prop is another object which is setting descriptor

     - Yes, basically.  When you do `obj.prop` and `prop` is a descriptor, then its `__get__` is called.  Note that `prop` is the descriptor, not `obj`.
   - when calculate some expression should get value such as `a + 5`. If a is have descriptor and will call `__get__`

     - No.  You can override such behavior with the `__add__` magic method, or similar methods for other operators
   - If a object simulate a function will call `__get__` to get function body first, and then call `__call__` to run the function.

     - I don't understand what this means, but I think no.  If the object defines `__call__`, then `obj()` calls its `__call__` without involving any descriptor.
2. set

   - When the object appear in the left side of assignment statement such as `obj = 5`

     - No.  Only when the descriptor is accessed *as an attribute* on the left side, as in `obj.prop = 5`, where prop is a descriptor.

The bottom line is that descriptors only work when they are attributes of classes.  Just creating a "bare" descriptor as you're trying to do (i.e., doing `obj = SomeDescriptorClass()`) won't do anything.

Also, as a side note, descriptors only work when set on new-style classes.  If you're using Python 2, this means that the class holding the descriptor has to inherit from `object`.

Comment: thank you. so, the descriptor only happen in property of object right?

Comment: I explain what i said `emulate function`. In the official [doc](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods). the emulation is using `__get__` to emulate `@classmethod`. so, i guess call a function will call `__get__` first.

Comment: @FreedomKnight: Yes.  If you google around you can find plenty of other questions about descriptors on this site, and descriptions on the web.

Comment: @FreedomKnight: In that example, the descriptor is again an attribute.  It happens to return a callable object, but that has nothing to do with how the descriptor protocl works.  It works just the same in that case as in any other case.

Answer (score 3):

`num = 2` makes `num` an `int` but not `Number` anymore.

Descriptor needs to be an attribute of instance and inherited from `object`.

```
class Number(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0

    def __get__(self, instance, obj):
        print("is getting number")
        return self.num

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print("is setting number")
        self.num = value

    # no need to define this for descriptor
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)

class A(object):
    num = Number()

n = A()
n.num = 5
print(n.num + 7)
```